# Transform a matrix to have determinant 1

Tags: matrices, geometry, normed-spaces, rotations

Is there a smooth function $f$ that I can apply to a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ such that $\det(f(\mathbf{A}))=1$? The transformation should have the property such that $\forall \mathbf{B} \in SO(n), \exists \mathbf{A} : f(\mathbf{A})=\mathbf{B}$, ie. there exists some input to this function such that every rotation matrix can be realized for a given dimension $n$.

### Motivation:

I've been playing around with using matrices instead of vectors in a deep learning model for natural language processing. When using "word vectors", it's useful to normalize them onto a unit sphere. This gives the vectors nice properties and is easy to do. I'd like to replace these vectors with matrices, specifically rotation matrices. However, a deep learning model will attempt any arbitrary values as input and I'd like to somehow "normalize" them into a proper rotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about
$$f(A)=\exp(A-A^t)?$$
Here $A^t$ is the transpose of $A$.
The image of this is $\text{SO}(n)$.

Comment: +1, but I might suggest something like $g(A) = e^{-\mathrm{tr} (A)} \exp(A)$ instead.  In your transformation, the symmetric part of $A$ doesn't affect the value of $f(A)$ at all, which means that a lot of information is "lost" under the transformation.  Note that the OP doesn't need the image to be exactly $\mathrm{SO}(n)$;  it just needs to contain all of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$.  (The image of $g$ is $\mathrm{SL}(n)$ instead, with the pre-image of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ being the set of antisymmetric matrices.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I like the idea of having all elements at my disposal, but I tested your $g(A)$ for a few random matrices and I'm not getting the desired property that $\det g(A) = 1$. I think I'm missing something critical in your comment about $SL$ instead of $SO$, can you explain more?

Comment: @Hooked:  My mistake;  the formula should be $g(A) = e^{-\mathrm{tr}(A)/n} \exp(A)$, where $n$ is the dimension of $A$.  (And, of course, you need to use the matrix exponential.)  Does this resolve your question about $SL$ vs. $SO$ as well?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert thank you, this fixes it! As an aside, I found that I have to use a Padé approximant to compute $\exp(A)$ in tensorflow (since only rudimentary matrix operations are defined for this language).

Comment: It's implemented in tensorflow now: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/expm